# Little trouble in open files using python in Mac os

Tags: python, macos

I have a CSV file in Documents , and I want to open it with python2.
 I run this

`print os.getcwd()
/Users/baicai`

My file in /Users/baicai/Documents/blabla.csv

I run this get error

```
df= open('/Documents/blabla.csv')
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Documents/blala.csv'

or this

```
f=open('/User/baicai/Documents/blabla.csv')
```

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/User/baicai/Documents/blabla.csv'

How to read? Thanks

Comment: obligatory "use a context manager" comment:  http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = open('Documents/blabla.csv')  # remove leading /
```

With the leading `/`, the operating system thinks you want an *absolute* path as opposed to a relative path.

or

```
f=open('/Users/baicai/Documents/blabla.csv')  # Users, not User
```

This one was just a typo :-)

Comment: Ack! you beat me by 5 seconds. Well played, sir. Well played